# Blackberry: change sorting of a KeywordFilterField

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, menu, menuitem

I have prepared a simple test case demonstrating my problem.

It is just 1 file (CheckMenu.java, listed below) and instantly runnable.

Once the user changes the sorting method by selecting 1 of the 2 MenuItems, how do I redraw the underlying [KeywordFilterField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/KeywordFilterField.html)? I've tried calling **myList.updateList()** and **myList.invalidate()** - it doesn't help - the myList items are not reorganized.

Also I wonder, what to use instead of the deprecated MenuItem.setText(String)?

[image]

```
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.util.Comparator;
import net.rim.device.api.util.StringUtilities;
import net.rim.device.api.collection.util.*;

public class CheckMenu extends UiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckMenu myApp = new CheckMenu();       
        myApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public CheckMenu() {        
        pushScreen(new MyScreen());
    }    
}

class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    KeywordFilterField myList = new KeywordFilterField();
    MyItemList myItems = new MyItemList();

    public MyScreen() {
        setTitle(myList.getKeywordField());

        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(1, "Eins"));
        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(2, "Zwei"));
        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(3, "Drei"));
        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(4, "Vier"));

        myList.setSourceList(myItems, new MyItem.MyProvider());
        // XXX commenting the line below does not help
        myList.setCallback(new MyListFieldCallback());
        add(myList);
    }

    private MenuItem numMenu = new MenuItem("num sort", 0, 0) {  
        public void run() {
            MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT = true;
            Status.show("Use " + toString());
            setText("num sort \u221A");
            alphaMenu.setText("alpha sort");
            myList.updateList();
        }
    };
    private MenuItem alphaMenu = new MenuItem("alpha sort", 1, 0) {  
        public void run() {
            MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT = false;
            Status.show("Use " + toString());
            setText("alpha sort \u221A");
            numMenu.setText("num sort");
            myList.updateList();
        }
    };

    protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
        super.makeMenu(menu, instance);
        menu.add(numMenu);
        menu.add(alphaMenu);
    }

    private class MyListFieldCallback implements ListFieldCallback {

        public void drawListRow(ListField list, Graphics g, int index, int y, int width) {
            Object obj = ((KeywordFilterField)list).getElementAt(index);
            if(obj != null && obj instanceof MyItem) {
                MyItem item = (MyItem) obj;
                g.drawText(item.toString(), 20 * (1 + index), y);
            } else if(index == 0) {
                g.drawText(list.getEmptyString(), 0, y);
            }
        }

        public Object get(ListField list, int index) { 
            return null; 
        }

        public int getPreferredWidth(ListField list) { 
            return 0; 
        }

        public int indexOfList(ListField list, String prefix, int start) { 
            return 0; 
        }
    }
}

class MyItemList extends SortedReadableList {
    public MyItemList() {
        super(new MyItem.MyComparator());        
    } 

    protected void doAdd(Object obj) {
        super.doAdd(obj);   
    }

    protected boolean doRemove(Object obj) {
        return super.doRemove(obj);        
    }
}

class MyItem {
    public static boolean NUMERIC_SORT;

    private int _num;
    private String _name;

    public MyItem(int num, String name) {
        _num = num;
        _name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return _num + ": " + _name;
    }

    static class MyComparator implements Comparator {
        public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
            if (! (obj1 instanceof MyItem && obj2 instanceof MyItem))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot compare non-MyItems");

            MyItem item1 = (MyItem) obj1;
            MyItem item2 = (MyItem) obj2;

            if (MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT) {
                if (item1._num == item2._num)
                    return 0;
                return (item1._num > item2._num ? 1 : -1);
            }

            return item1._name.compareTo(item2._name);
        }
    }

    static class MyProvider implements KeywordProvider {
        public String[] getKeywords(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof MyItem) {
                MyItem item = (MyItem) obj;
                return new String[]{ Integer.toString(item._num), item._name };
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I've updated the code to use makeMenu() as suggested by Arhimed.
I've also posted my question [at the BlackBerry forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Change-sorting-of-a-KeywordFilterField/td-p/1016663).

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: +1 for a perfectly structurized/prepared question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your problem..... But as I see, this code works fine on simulator

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.util.Comparator;
import net.rim.device.api.util.StringUtilities;
import net.rim.device.api.collection.util.*;

public class CheckMenu extends UiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckMenu myApp = new CheckMenu();       
        myApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public CheckMenu() {        
        pushScreen(new MyScreen());
    }    
}

class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    KeywordFilterField myList = new KeywordFilterField();
    MyItemList myItems = new MyItemList();

    public MyScreen() {
        setTitle(myList.getKeywordField());

        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(1, "Eins"));
        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(2, "Zwei"));
        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(3, "Drei"));
        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(4, "Vier"));

        myList.setSourceList(myItems, new MyItem.MyProvider());
        // XXX commenting the line below does not help
        myList.setCallback(new MyListFieldCallback());
        add(myList);
    }

    private MenuItem numMenu = new MenuItem("num sort", 0, 0) {  
    public void run() {
        MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT = true;
        Status.show("Use " + toString());
        setText("num sort \u221A");
        alphaMenu.setText("alpha sort");
        myItems.sort();
        myList.updateList();
    }
};
private MenuItem alphaMenu = new MenuItem("alpha sort", 1, 0) {  
    public void run() {
        MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT = false;
        Status.show("Use " + toString());
        setText("alpha sort \u221A");
        numMenu.setText("num sort");
        myItems.sort();
        myList.updateList();
    }
};

protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
    super.makeMenu(menu, instance);
    menu.add(numMenu);
    menu.add(alphaMenu);
}

private class MyListFieldCallback implements ListFieldCallback {

    public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g, int index, int y, int    width) {
        Object obj = ((KeywordFilterField)listField).getElementAt(index);
        if(obj != null && obj instanceof MyItem) {
            MyItem item = (MyItem) obj;
            g.drawText(item.toString(), 20 * (1 + index), y);
        } else if(index == 0) {
            g.drawText("ssssssss", 0, y);
        }
    }

    public Object get(ListField listField, int index) { 
        return null; 
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) { 
        return 0; 
    }

    public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) { 
        return 0; 
    }
}
}

class MyItemList extends SortedReadableList {
    public MyItemList() {
        super(new MyItem.MyComparator());        
    } 

    protected void doAdd(Object obj) {
        super.doAdd(obj);   
    }

    protected boolean doRemove(Object obj) {
        return super.doRemove(obj);        
    }
 }

class MyItem {
    public static boolean NUMERIC_SORT;

    private int _num;
    private String _name;

    public MyItem(int num, String name) {
        _num = num;
        _name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return _num + ": " + _name;
    }

    static class MyComparator implements Comparator {
        public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
            if (! (obj1 instanceof MyItem && obj2 instanceof MyItem))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot compare non-MyItems");

            MyItem item1 = (MyItem) obj1;
            MyItem item2 = (MyItem) obj2;

            if (MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT) {
                if (item1._num == item2._num)
                    return 0;
                return (item1._num > item2._num ? 1 : -1);
            }

            return item1._name.compareTo(item2._name);
        }
    }

    static class MyProvider implements KeywordProvider {
        public String[] getKeywords(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof MyItem) {
                MyItem item = (MyItem) obj;
                return new String[]{ Integer.toString(item._num), item._name };
            }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When you change the sorting numeric <-> alphabetic in the menu - the ListField should display the 4 rows in different order

Comment: Yes. When I change the sorting numeric <-> alphabetic in the menu - the ListField display the 4 rows in different order.   I just add myItems.sort(); to your code.

Comment: True, that is the solution for my problem (sorry, missed your addition at first)! It seems more natural to me than re-assigning Comparator as Arhimed suggests.

Comment: re-assigning Comparator was a quick fix to cause resorting without the need for me to dig in the API docs. :) I thought it was enough for you just to get the idea on what is wrong with your workflow/logic.

Answer (score 0):

> 1). How can I modify a MenuItem text? I'd
>   like to display/hide a check mark
>   symbol \u221A - depending on which
>   sorting order is currently selected by
>   the user. The setText(String text)
>   method is deprecated and I'm not sure
>   how to use the setText(StringProvider
>   text)?

Instead of using `addMenuItem(myMenu1);` override `makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance)`:

```
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
    super.makeMenu(menu, instance);

    // add menu items on-the-fly
    // generating their labels in accordance to some conditions
    menu.add(new MenuItem("any label", 1, 1) {
        public void run() {
            // do smth useful
        }
    });
}
```

> 2). Once the user changes the sorting method by selecting 1 of the 2
>   MenuItems, how do I redraw the
>   underlying KeywordFilterField? I've
>   tried calling myList.updateList() and
>   myList.invalidate() - it doesn't help.

Try to comment out the `myList.setCallback(new MyListFieldCallback());` line. I believe `KeywordFilterField` already implements this callback in some specific way, so by setting your custom `ListFieldCallback` you break the default/expected behaviour.

**UPDATE** about menu items:

Get rid of `private MenuItem alphaMenu` and `private MenuItem numMenu` fields completely. Generate those menu items on the fly:

```
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
    super.makeMenu(menu, instance);

    String label = "num sort" + (MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT ? " \u221A" : "");

    menu.add(new MenuItem(label, 0, 0) {  
        public void run() {
            MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT = true;
            Status.show("Use " + toString());
            // setText("num sort \u221A");
            // alphaMenu.setText("alpha sort");
            myList.updateList();
        }
    });

    label = "alpha sort" + (MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT ? "" : " \u221A");

    menu.add(new MenuItem(label, 1, 0) {
        public void run() {
            MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT = false;
            Status.show("Use " + toString());
            // setText("alpha sort \u221A");
            // numMenu.setText("num sort");
            myList.updateList();
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE** on the major problem:

```
class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    KeywordFilterField myList = new KeywordFilterField();
    MyItemList myItems = new MyItemList();

    public MyScreen() {
        setTitle(myList.getKeywordField());

        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(1, "Eins"));
        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(2, "Zwei"));
        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(3, "Drei"));
        myItems.doAdd(new MyItem(4, "Vier"));

        myList.setSourceList(myItems, new MyItem.MyProvider());

        // XXX commenting the line below does not help
        myList.setCallback(new MyListFieldCallback());
        add(myList);
    }

    protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
        super.makeMenu(menu, instance);

        String label = "num sort" + (MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT ? " \u221A" : "");

        menu.add(new MenuItem(label, 0, 0) {  
            public void run() {
                MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT = true;
                Status.show("Use " + toString());
                // setText("num sort \u221A");
                // alphaMenu.setText("alpha sort");

                myItems.setComparator(new MyItem.MyComparator());
                myList.updateList();
            }
        });

        label = "alpha sort" + (MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT ? "" : " \u221A");

        menu.add(new MenuItem(label, 1, 0) {
            public void run() {
                MyItem.NUMERIC_SORT = false;
                Status.show("Use " + toString());
                // setText("alpha sort \u221A");
                // numMenu.setText("num sort");

                myItems.setComparator(new MyItem.MyComparator());
                myList.updateList();
            }
        });

    }

// .. the rest of the code is the same
```

Comment: 1) Thanks, but how will changing from addMenuItem to makeMenu help me changing menu texts during runtime?

Comment: Make your menu texts variables, and change them via conditionals, makeMenu() is a dynamic method, it only occurs when the menu is requested

Comment: yes, I mean don't use `addMenuItem` at all. Override `makeMenu` instead, it will be called each time user presses Menu button on device.

Comment: Hello! I've updated my code to use makeMenu, but still wonder, what to use instead of the setText(String). And also the major problem of the list items order not being changed is not fixed by commenting myList.setCallback(new MyListFieldCallback()) out.

Comment: @Alexander Farber: I added UPDATE section on how to use `makeMenu`. However I still out of ideas on the major problem with the list field. I need to think about this..

Comment: Thanks for coming back to my question

Comment: @Alexander Farber: I've just added the UPDATE on the major problem. Now it filters the list as required. The problem was the underlying collection was not resorted - simply calling the `myList.updateList()` did not cause the underlying collection to be resorted. So you need to explicitly resort the list. Instead of digging in APIs on how to resort it I just reinited the list from zero (and this action implies sorting being executed).

Comment: @Alexander Farber: oops, looks like now filter does not work.

Comment: @Alexander Farber: finally fixed the issue (see the code). No need to recreate the list from zero, just resort the list by resetting a Comparator.

Comment: Thank you for you replies, but oxigen's solution seems more natural to me. In fact I wonder, why didn't I call sort() myself in the 1st place